# CSS and flexbox responsive layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to make two divs a certain size inside my react page jsx. I am using flex box in the css. on my home-page i have a homepage parent div and then inside that div i have two children div's. my css file looks like this. The .App is the main body, then i have .home-page which is my main div and then nested in that is .home-page-left-container and the .home-page-right-container. I would like the left container to take up 80% of the page and the right container to take up 20% but if you are looking on your fine i would like the flexbox to work so that then both divs look like they are on top of eachother on the phone.

```
.App {
  max-width: 900px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.home-page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.home-page-left-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 60vh;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 10px;
  float:left;
}
.home-page-right-container {
  padding: 10px;
  background: beige;
  width: 20%;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Please attach the rendered HTML

Comment: Use [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and do some more reading on basic responsive design

Comment: When the container is `display: flex` it arranges its children according to flex-grow, flex-shrink, and flex-basis. Your `width` rules aren't going to do what you expect here. And why are they `float: left`? There are vanishingly few scenarios where float is still useful, and this doesn't appear to be one of them. Once that's all sorted out you could handle your responsiveness via a media query and `flex-direction` or by setting `min-width` and `flex-wrap`.